# Subtract 2 dataframes with different number of rows and taking in consideration the Date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm working on the following code :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Date'] = ["29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "01/08/2021", "01/08/2021", "02/08/2021"]
df1['Time'] = ["06:48:00", "06:52:00", "06:56:00", "06:59:00", "07:14:00", "07:24:00", "07:40:00", "07:45:00", "08:42:00", "08:45:00", "08:52:00", "08:55:00", "09:07:00"]
df1['Column1'] = [0.0001, 0.002, 0.004, 0.5, 0.005, 0.0006, 0.08, 0.07, 0.003, 0.02, 0.0002, 0.0045, 0.0034]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Date'] = ["29/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "01/08/2021", "02/08/2021"]
df2['Column1'] = [0.0056, 0.0594, 0.959, 0.0034, 0.00065]
```

**I want to subtract the df2['Column1'] values from the df1['Column1] values, for each day in a new dataframe.**

For example, for the first date (which is 29/07/2021) we will have a dataframe like this :

```
Date       New_Column
29/07/2021 0.0001-0.0056
29/07/2021 0.002-0.0056
29/07/2021 0.004-0.0056
29/07/2021 0.5-0.0056
```

And so on for each date we will subtract one value that is related to one date from df2 from different values that are related to one date in df1.

Thank you.

Comment: are there duplicate dates in `df2`?

Comment: No only one date with one value in Column1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no duplicate dates in `df2`, then we can create a mapping from dates to values and `map` it to `Date` column in `df1`. Then we can simply subtract the corresponding values:

```
df1['New Column'] = df1['Column1'] - df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['Column1'])
```

Output:

```
          Date      Time  Column1  New Column
0   29/07/2021  06:48:00   0.0001    -0.00550
1   29/07/2021  06:52:00   0.0020    -0.00360
2   29/07/2021  06:56:00   0.0040    -0.00160
3   29/07/2021  06:59:00   0.5000     0.49440
4   30/07/2021  07:14:00   0.0050    -0.05440
5   30/07/2021  07:24:00   0.0006    -0.05880
6   30/07/2021  07:40:00   0.0800     0.02060
7   30/07/2021  07:45:00   0.0700     0.01060
8   31/07/2021  08:42:00   0.0030    -0.95600
9   31/07/2021  08:45:00   0.0200    -0.93900
10  01/08/2021  08:52:00   0.0002    -0.00320
11  01/08/2021  08:55:00   0.0045     0.00110
12  02/08/2021  09:07:00   0.0034     0.00275
```